# Classification of representations of CCR algebras?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, quantum-field-theory, oa.operator-algebras

Hi,

I'm wondering if there is a some classification of representations of CCR algebras (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CCR_algebra), where say the underlying vector space is a separable Hilbert space.

My naive understanding is that for a QFT, one wants a representation of a CCR algebra satisfying certain properties.

Comment: Good question.  I am more familiar with the fermionic case (i.e., CAR as opposed to CCR) where the uniqueness theorem fails basically due to the existence of Bogoljubov transformations relating different inequivalent vacua.  A similar story should hold for the CCR case, but since I'm not sure and unable to check at present, I'll leave this as a commment.

Comment: I think finite dimensional reps are dealt with here
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone-von_Neumann_theorem

For the more generaly case, I'm not sure. Maybe an operator algebras or C^*-algebras tag should be added to lure someone more suited to answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question depends very much on the regularity that you demand. You have to decide before asking the question which operators are supposed to be self-adjoint or merely symmetric as unbounded operators etc. Weyl has solved the problem by exponentiating everything and looking at the resulting relations. This however gives rise to some *unphysical* representations.

Buchholz and Grundling give a new $C^\star$-algebraic approach to the problem in [0705.1988](http://arxiv.org/abs/0705.1988) using the notion of resolvent algebra. This settles the problem very nicely from a mathematical and physical perspective.